# How do i reset values of dynamically created controls on ASP .NET c# page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an array of buttons added to a panel control and need to reset them to their original values, is this possible pragmatically?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RenderTable();
}
private void RenderTable()
{
    Button[] board = new Button[9];
    for(int i =0; i <board.Length; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new Button();
        board[i].Text = " ";
        board[i].Width= board[i].Height = 50;
        board[i].Click += PlayerClick;
        board[i].ID = "pos" + i;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(board[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the values yourself in session, viewstate, or simply look in the post values for them.  You're already using a custom ID so use those values if you use the form post method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to store an array of the original values as well, and loop through reassigning them.

Answer (score 0):

panel.Controls.Clear() ?